# Catastrophic failure when publishing an InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, infopath, publishing

I have a TeamSite on SharePoint (Office 365) and used to manage all my forms using InfoPath. Since a couple of days ago, when I create any **NEW** list, open the form on InfoPath Designer 2013 and try to publish, I receive the following error (even if I try directly to publishing the form without any changes):

“The publish operation could not be completed. It cannot be determined if the form template was successfully published. Try publishing the form template again, or change the list settings to use the default SharePoint form. Catastrophic failure”

However, if I try the same procedure on **OLD** lists (on the same SharePoint site), it works perfectly.

Any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

InfoPath custom form support was removed from SharePoint Online. You'll need to use the out of the box SharePoint form or customized with Power Apps.

If you go to the List/Library Settings -> Form settings, you'll see InfoPath was removed.

Comment: I can see The InfoPath option for old and new sites!

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that is correct.  We are on SP Online and still have the option to customize forms using InfoPath but it no longer works when we try to publish in new lists.  Existing lists that have previously been customized do still work.  I think MS broke something.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft obviously hasn't deleted the Infopath functionality. It is set to stop supporting Infopath services in 2026.

This problem occured when i made a list from the modern Home page.
Once i created a list from the New->Dropdown->List, i could not upload new infopath forms to the sharepoint online list.

How i resolved the issue:
Create the list from the "add an app" option and by picking custom list.

I believe that it has to do with some initialization/creation scripts.

To be fair, though... Microsoft has already announced the End of Support for infopath services, so people should stop using this technology.