# Unable to publish informPath Forms to SharePointOnline site

Tags: sharepoint-online

Am currently facing an issue with publishing InforPath Ms Form to our Sharepointonline site, which started last week Thursday, any solutions?

1. Can edit and publish to old list.
2. Can publish new forms to new list.

"The publish operation could not be completed. It cannot be determined if the form template was successfully published. Try publishing the form template again, or change the list settings to use the default SharePoint form. Catastrophic failure”

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I can successfully publish form in some lists and some not. However, I am not able to reproduce your issue.
I found a [similar post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288308/catastrophic-failure-when-publishing-an-infopath-form) that a user said he encountered the same error in SPO but not sure the cause and solution.

As you may know,InfoPath has reached the countdown of its life cycle, I would suggest you open a service request for more help and information.

And it is more recommended to find some alternatives in the future.