# extract the email address from the claim field inside the response message from "Get Items" action

Tags: flow, power-automate, json

I have the following Get Items action:-

[image]

where the response body will be as follow:-

[image]

now i need to extract the email address from the claim field as follow, where i need the email to be added inside "Grant access to item or file"? any advice how i can do such an extract?

Comment: Is `ResponsiblePerson` column of type "Person or Group" (I think so)? If yes, you should get the email address in response of "Get items" action similar to [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/how-to-extract-email-address-from-a-sharepoint-person-or-group/td-p/124642).

Comment: @GaneshSanap i tired this but the email will be empty.. and yes the ResponsiblePerson is of type People or group

Comment: @GaneshSanap as you can see from the picture i provided there is no email field inside the returned json

Comment: Strange...I just tried this by creating a flow & I am getting email address in response of "Get items" action.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it.
I currently get an item with a filter query by executing a Get Items step in Flow.

Another thing to note is that **i just created the list and added a list column.**
as you can see from the below screenshots i get all of the attributes that are about a person field.

[image: flow screenshot]

[image: flow JSON results]

You might not be getting the properties if the list or column was created a long time ago OR (something else that i have noticed) if you created your list from the "add an app" button, which is classic experience.

Another thing that might be in place is that the Get Items actions is somehow stuck(this has occured to me, not all the time, but it has). In this case, please delete the step and recreate it.

Have you tried making a new list and trying the flow on the new list?
How was the list created?

[Edit] i'm just stressing out the fact that the list was just created with a certain way because i had faced an unexplained bug when trying to publish an infopath form to a list, which i described [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/293534/78095)